# How to determine the difference between object distance and image distance?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics

[image]

How do we derrive the last equation? Whatever I tried it didn't work...

Oh man I just saw, that all the did is write $b=3m-g$, how was is it possible for me to miss it...

Comment: see answers below, but I wonder if you were confused by the first equation at the top of your question because you don't need to use this to get the answer....

Comment: Use Mathjax, not image please..

Comment: Why and why are at least 15 characters required in the comment section?

Comment: @user42141 probably need 15 characters to stop comments like 'ahh'  or 'no Im not sure' or 'hi' or 'thanks'

Answer (score 1):

Start with

${b \over g }=m$

and rearrange this equation to get $b$ in terms of $g$

Then you can substitute your expression for $b$ into

$g+b=3m$

and you should get the answer.... does this help?

Comment: Ahh, you beat me to it! Nice.

Answer (score 1):

Do some substitution:

Re-arrange
$$g+b=3m$$
to become
$$b=3m-g$$
With substitution,
$$\frac{b}{g}=10$$
becomes
$$\frac{3m-g}{g}=10$$
Can you go from here?

Comment: I like your answer too!

Comment: @tom I was trying to not give too much away, just like you thought.